# Plotly: How to select scatter plot marker size and colour values from dropdown?

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, plotly

I’m trying to use the built in plotly widgets to select values for marker size and color in `scatter` and `scatter_3d` from plotly express. I can get this working using `ipywidgets` but then it resets the plot to the original orientation (3D). But when using `updatemenus` instead nothing changes at all.

Here’s an example code:

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()


fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
                   color='species', size='petal_length' ,text='species_id'               )
fig.update_layout(scene_aspectmode='data')

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[
                    dict(
                        buttons=list([
                         dict(
                             args=['size','sepal_length'],
                             label='sepal length',
                             method='update'
                         ),
                         dict(
                             args=['size','sepal_width'],
                             label='sepal width',
                             method='update'
                         )         
                        ]),
                        showactive=True,
                        )                        
                     ])

fig.show()
```

I’ve tried a number of variations to `arg`s and different `methods`.

This example with `ipywidgets` works, but it resets the view if plot has been zoomed or rotated.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interactive, interact, interact_manual, Layout

df = px.data.iris()

sel_size= widgets.Dropdown(
    options=sorted(df.columns),    
    description='Size',
    value='sepal_length'
)


sel_colour= widgets.Dropdown(
    options=sorted(df.columns),    
    description='Colour',
    value='species'
)

@interact
def get_column(size=sel_size,color=sel_colour):        
    scatter3D_fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
                   color='species', size='petal_length' ,text='species_id',opacity=0.5)
    scatter3D_fig.update_layout(scene_aspectmode='data')
    scatter3D_fig.show()
```

Modified from @vestland's answer this is close to what I want. I can select different data for marker size and color, without changing the camera/eye position. Although when I select a categorical variable for color, changing the marker symbol only changes them for one category.

```
from plotly import tools
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


app = JupyterDash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE])


# colors = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly
colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'black', 'yellow']
symbols = ['circle', 'circle-open', 'square', 'square-open', 'diamond', 'diamond-open', 'cross', 'x']
columns = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width', 'species', 'species_id']

# Set up well organized controls in a dbc.Card()
controls = dbc.Card([dbc.FormGroup([dbc.Label("Color"),
                                    dcc.Dropdown(id='ctrl_color',
                                                 options= [{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in columns],
#                                                   value=colors[0]
                                                  value='species'
                                                ),
                                   ],),
                    dbc.FormGroup([dbc.Label("Symbol"),
                                   dcc.Dropdown(id='ctrl_symbol',
                                                options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in symbols],
                                                value=symbols[0],
                                                ),
                                   ],),
                    dbc.FormGroup([dbc.Label("Size"),
                                   dcc.Dropdown(id='ctrl_size',
                                                options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in columns],
                                                value='petal_length',
                                                ),
                                    ],)                     
                    ],
                    body=True,
                    style = {'font-size': 'large'}
                    )

# Set up the app layout using dbc.Container(), dbc.Row(), and dbc.Col()
app.layout = dbc.Container([html.H1("Marker color, symbol and size"),
                            html.Hr(),
                            html.Div(id="campos"),
                            dbc.Row([dbc.Col([controls],xs = 4),
                                     dbc.Col([dbc.Row([dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="market_graph")),])]),
                                    ]),
                            html.Br(),
                            ],
                            fluid=True,
                            )

# 3D figure with callbacks for color, symbol and size
@app.callback(
    [Output("campos", "children"),Output("market_graph", "figure")],
    [
        Input("market_graph", "relayoutData"),
        Input("ctrl_color", "value"),
        Input("ctrl_symbol", "value"),
        Input("ctrl_size", "value"),        
    ],
)
def history_graph(data,color, symbol, size):
    df = px.data.iris()
    fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',size=size,color=color)

#     fig.data[0].update(marker_color=color)
    fig.data[0].update(marker_symbol=symbol)
#     fig.data[0].update(marker_size=size)

    fig.update_layout(uirevision='constant')
    fig.update_layout(template = 'plotly_dark')
    return str(data),fig

app.run_server(mode='inline', port = 8008)
```

Comment: Please share a runnable snippet with a sample of your data.

Comment: I've updated to use an example from the iris data set, where I'm trying to set marker size.

Comment: Hi @vestland, I take it then it isn't currently possible to do this with plotly?

Comment: It sure does not seem that way. And I've tried! And actually ended up working on a similar question myself with a few details added to it. It's most certainly a possibility with Plotly Dash though if that could be of interest...

Comment: Thanks, I still need to look into Dash

Comment: I'll write up a suggestion using Dash then so you can see how you like it.

Comment: How did the JupyterDash approach work out for you?

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. An improvement in layout. Although it doesn't seem to provide a means to manipulate which data is used for marker properties. That seems to require some underlying changes to plotly.

Alternatively, I'm trying to see if there's a way to retrieve the current camera settings and wrap that in @interact, but that doesn't seem simple either.

Comment: So it turns out I can change underlying data with dash without resetting the camera. I get some odd behavior with marker selection though when I choose a categorical for color

Comment: I'm glad my suggestion helped you out. If you'd like solutions to `when I select a categorical variable for color, changing the marker symbol only changes them for one category.`, then please consider writing that up as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet below will produce a Dash App that let's you control the color, symbol and size of your 3D markers using dropdown menus. This is perhaps not perfect for `'size'`, but we can change that if this is otherwise something you can use.

With this setup, the color, sizes and symbol are controlled through:

```
fig.data[0].update(marker_color=color)
fig.data[0].update(marker_symbol=symbol)
fig.data[0].update(marker_size=size)
```

And this sweet little detail takes care of the:

> This example with ipywidgets works, but it resets the view if plot has
> been zoomed or rotated.

```
fig.update_layout(uirevision='constant')
```

#### Plot 1: Default selections

[image]

#### Plot 2: Some other selections

[image]

#### Complete code using JupyterDash and some bootstrap components

```
import plotly as py
import pandas as pd

from plotly import tools
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


app = JupyterDash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE])


# colors = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly
colors = ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'black', 'yellow']
symbols = ['circle', 'circle-open', 'square', 'square-open', 'diamond', 'diamond-open', 'cross', 'x']


# Set up well organized controls in a dbc.Card()
controls = dbc.Card([dbc.FormGroup([dbc.Label("Color"),
                                    dcc.Dropdown(id='ctrl_color',
                                                 options= [{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in colors],
                                                  value=colors[0]
                                                ),
                                   ],),
                    dbc.FormGroup([dbc.Label("Symbol"),
                                   dcc.Dropdown(id='ctrl_symbol',
                                                options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in symbols],
                                                value=symbols[0],
                                                ),
                                   ],),
                    dbc.FormGroup([dbc.Label("Size"),
                                   dcc.Dropdown(id='ctrl_size',
                                                options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in [8,10,12,14,16]],
                                                value=8,
                                                ),
                                    ],)
                    ],
                    body=True,
                    style = {'font-size': 'large'}
                    )

# Set up the app layout using dbc.Container(), dbc.Row(), and dbc.Col()
app.layout = dbc.Container([html.H1("Marker color, symbol and size"),
                            html.Hr(),
                            dbc.Row([dbc.Col([controls],xs = 4),
                                     dbc.Col([dbc.Row([dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="market_graph")),])]),
                                    ]),
                            html.Br(),
                            ],
                            fluid=True,
                            )

# 3D figure with callbacks for color, symbol and size
@app.callback(
    Output("market_graph", "figure"),
    [
        Input("ctrl_color", "value"),
        Input("ctrl_symbol", "value"),
        Input("ctrl_size", "value"),
    ],
)
def history_graph(color, symbol, size):
    df = px.data.iris()
    fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width')

    fig.data[0].update(marker_color=color)
    fig.data[0].update(marker_symbol=symbol)
    fig.data[0].update(marker_size=size)

    fig.update_layout(uirevision='constant')
    fig.update_layout(template = 'plotly_dark')
    return fig

app.run_server(mode='inline', port = 8007)
```